# Consolidating Excel worksheet rows into one worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, xlsx, xlsm

I have an Excel workbook that has several worksheet (by team member name).  Each team member maintains a list of projects/tasks.  All column titles in each worksheet are identical.

I need a worksheet within the same workbook that consolidates all projects from each team members' worksheet for a one time review instead of the manager having to jump between multiple tabs.

The consolidated (main worksheet) worksheet needs to automatically update as employees changes within cells, or add/remove rows.

Is there a macro or function in MS Excel 2007 that enables thus functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do it without a macro:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213933

As the commenter in this post mentioned, I'll explain what's in the link for archival reasons. The function there is INDIRECT(), which expects an address given as a string and returns you its contents. It will allow you to perform calculations cross-worksheet.

Comment: Please note that you should post the useful points of an answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted as ["Not an Answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.